# Can I merge these g++ calls into one?

Tags: c++, g++, command-line-interface

```
g++ -I include/ -I include/gliese/ -I include/othello/ -c src/OthelloHeuristics.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/OthelloHeuristics.o
g++ -I include/ -I include/gliese/ -I include/othello/ -c src/OthelloNegamaxSearch.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/OthelloNegamaxSearch.o
g++ -I include/ -I include/gliese/ -I include/othello/ -c src/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/main.o
g++ -L lib -l othello -l SDL_image -l SDL_ttf -l SDL obj/Debug/src/main.o obj/Debug/src/OthelloHeuristics.o obj/Debug/src/OthelloNegamaxSearch.o -o bin/Debug/othello
```

Currently I'm running those lines in order to build a game, and it works. But is there anyway to merge them into one? (in order to gain some speed). Thanks!

Comment: considered using a script or a make file?

Comment: I don't think you can increase compilation speed, finally compiler must do the same work. But using variables can improve makefile/script readability and maintenance.

Comment: Use a make file, i.e., with a file named Makefile in the same directory, so that you can run 'make' in the directory to build the game. I don't think you can increase speed by "merging" the commands into one because the compiler has to do the same amount of job.

Comment: [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Comment: You won't gain any noticeable speed by reducing the number of compiler invocations. Actually you'd be better of with *maximizing* the number of invocations (ie. one command line per translation unit) and using `make` to execute several jobs in parallel (`-j` option).

Comment: Note: in most cases you want to amend your library clauses (like `-l othello -l SDL_image -l SDL_ttf -l SDL`) *after* the object code being linked, with independent libraries *last*. Some linkers are that picky.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
g++ -I include/gliese/ -c src/OthelloHeuristics.cpp src/OthelloNegamaxSearch.cpp  src/main.cpp 

g++ -L lib -l othello -l SDL_image -l SDL_ttf -l SDL obj/Debug/src/*.o -o bin/Debug/othello
```